# Выдает ошибку Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
        <?php
session_start ();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db ($db, 'users');
$select = @mysqli_query($db, "SELECT log,passw FROM test1 ");
if (!$select) exit ('#110');
$row = @mysqli_fetch_row ($select);
if(!row) exit ('#111');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Админ Панель</h1>
<div style="background-color: #d3d3d3; width: 200px; padding: 10px">
    <form method="post">
    login:<br>
    <input name="log" type="text"><br>
    password:<br>
    <input name="passw" type="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" style="cursor: pointer"><br><br>
    </form>
    <?php
    if($_POST['button']){
        $log = $_POST['log'];
        $passw = $_POST['passw'];

        if(($log == $row[0]) and ($passw == $row[1])){
            $_SESSION['auth'] = $log;
            echo "Enter to admin -> <a href='admin.php'> admin </a>";
        }else{
            return exit ('Not correct');
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: уберите пробел перед началом <?php

Comment: а где код на который ругаеться то? где собственно вы устанавливаете эту cookie

Comment: Я их убрал и ничего 2 ошибки выдает 
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost1\admin\index.php:1) in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost1\admin\index.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost1\admin\index.php:1) in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost1\admin\index.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема заключается в том что у вас до начала скрипта имеются пробелы, перед `<?php` удалите пробелы

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Просто кодировка стояла utf-8 без BOM

Comment: наоборот.... она была **с** BOM а нужно **без** BOM........собственно в ссылке на дубликат об этом написано